# Setting up JDBC password dynamically on Apache Zeppelin

Tags: jdbc, apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to set the default.password dynamically e.g. from a file? We have connected Presto to Zeppelin with a JDBC connector successfully, however we are using a different authentication method that requires us to renew the password every day. I have checked the current gitHub repository and found out that there is an interpreter.json that takes in default.password from the interpreter settings on Zeppelin. If I change the default.password to an environment variable, will it affect other JDBC interpreters. Is there a workaround?

Links to the repository:
https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/e63ba8e897a522c6cad099286110c2eaa1496912/jdbc/src/main/resources/interpreter-setting.json

https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/8f45fefb1c45ab163bedb94e3d9a9ef8a35afd91/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/jdbc/JDBCInterpreter.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The interpreter.json in the config file stores all the information of each JDBC connection. So, by updating the password with jq command and restarting Zeppelin every day, this will update the password dynamically.